# LXDE Authentication Required for shutdown when logging in using NIS

Tags: systemd, session, lxde, debian-buster, authorization

This problem is solved, but I wanted to document it so I am able to find it again the next time. And for the benefit of other users.

Debian 10 Buster
4.19.0-12-amd64
LXDE
Systemd

This error message occurs when trying to shutdown, hibernate or suspend:
**GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InteractiveAuthorizationRequired: Interactive authentication required.**

Two related errors also occur:

After login into LXDE a dialog appears with the message: **No session for pid XXXX**. Where XXXX is the pid of the polkitd process.

Pulseaudio also does not start at login. It can be started from within a console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by systemd not assigning a seat to the current user when signing in with systemd.

The error is different, but is is caused by exactly the same reason as described [in this post:](https://superuser.com/questions/1563951/systemd-does-not-assign-a-seat-to-my-session-when-using-nis-authentication)

The easiest solution is the second option described in the answer by **user1686**.:

Use systemctl edit --full systemd-logind to disable the network restrictions in systemd-logind, by removing the IPAddressDeny= and RestrictAddressFamilies= options.

I modified the configuration to this:

IPAddressDeny=
IPAddressAllow=my.local.subnet/mask
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_NETLINK AF_INET AF_INET6

That is sufficient to make LXDE behave as expected.