# systemd-logind ProtectHostname=yes prevents seat creation when using NIS in LXDE

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, session, lxde

systemd version 246
Debian Bullseye
Kernel 5.9.0-1-amd64

I don't exaclty know when this was introduced. The directive was not present yet in systemd version 241.

When no seat is created, the user is not authorized to logout/shutdown, pulseaudio does not start, (some) devices are not accessible and maybe some more.

systemd-logind has given me quite some headaches. Not only to find the problem once, but with each update of systemd it seems that new issues are being created.

Related questions (by me as well) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1563951/systemd-does-not-assign-a-seat-to-my-session-when-using-nis-authentication) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1600867/lxde-authentication-required-for-shutdown-when-logging-in-using-nis).

After installing Debian Bullseye I was not able to get a seat assigned to my session again. This time the culprit was **ProtectHostname=yes** in systemd-logind.service. Commenting this line out, or **ProtectHostname=no** solves the problem. The latter is the defualt setting.

My problem is not just how to solve this. With this new version of systemd, another 10-20 lines were added to systemd-logind.service. I would like to understand and find those errors instead of commenting out directives by trial and error.

I have searched in journalctl, syslog, auth.log and .xsession-errors for the string "hostname" and did not find any error related to hostname whatsoever. That makes it very difficult to understand or debug or solving the problem.

The [systemd manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProtectHostname=) mentions the ProtectHostname directive but explains exactly nothing about why it is used/needed, what effects it has on a session, and why it does not work when network authentication (NIS) is used.

So, the question is: what is happening here and why?

For the sake of completeness below the contents of systemd-logind.service and nssswitch.conf

```
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=User Login Management
Documentation=man:systemd-logind.service(8) man:logind.conf(5)
Documentation=https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind
Documentation=https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
Wants=user.slice modprobe@drm.service
After=nss-user-lookup.target user.slice modprobe@drm.service
ConditionPathExists=/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service

# Ask for the dbus socket.
Wants=dbus.socket
After=dbus.socket

[Service]
BusName=org.freedesktop.login1
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYS_ADMIN CAP_MAC_ADMIN CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL CAP_CHOWN CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_FOWNER CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE
DeviceAllow=block-* r
DeviceAllow=char-/dev/console rw
DeviceAllow=char-drm rw
DeviceAllow=char-input rw
DeviceAllow=char-tty rw
DeviceAllow=char-vcs rw
# Make sure the DeviceAllow= lines above can work correctly when referenceing char-drm
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
FileDescriptorStoreMax=512
#IPAddressDeny=
IPAddressAllow=192.168.110.0/24
LockPersonality=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
ProtectClock=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectHostname=no
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelLogs=yes
ProtectSystem=strict
ReadWritePaths=/etc /run
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_NETLINK AF_INET AF_INET6
RestrictNamespaces=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
RestrictSUIDSGID=yes
RuntimeDirectory=systemd/sessions systemd/seats systemd/users systemd/inhibit systemd/shutdown
RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=yes
StateDirectory=systemd/linger
SystemCallArchitectures=native
SystemCallErrorNumber=EPERM
SystemCallFilter=@system-service
WatchdogSec=3min

# Increase the default a bit in order to allow many simultaneous logins since
# we keep one fd open per session.
LimitNOFILE=524288


# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd nis
group:          files systemd nis
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns nis
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: When I set ProtectHostname=yes. Open a console and restart systemd-logind. The problem does NOT occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ProtectHostname=" creates a new *UTS namespace*, similar to how PrivateNetwork= creates a new network namespace and PrivateTmp= creates a new mount namespace. (Its goal is to prevent the process from changing the system's hostname, which could in theory cause security issues with hostname-bound 'sudo' policies, or LDAP authorization checks, etc.)

The "UTS namespace" covers parameters returned by [the uname() call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) in `struct utsname` – this includes some read-only data (kernel version); the hostname (obviously); *and the NIS domain name.* (It's quite unclear why the NIS domain name is stored in kernel space, but on Linux it is.)

So if your boot process goes such that logind is started *before* the NIS client is brought up and the default domain name is set, then logind's private UTS namespace will still have an older copy of 'struct utsname' containing an empty NIS domain name. When logind tries to resolve usernames through libnss_nis, the latter will give up as the domain name is not set.

```
# strace -v -e uname ypdomainname
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="ember", release="5.4.70-1-lts",
       version="#1 SMP Wed, 07 Oct 2020 23:54:51 +0000", machine="x86_64",
       domainname="example.com"}) = 0
example.com
+++ exited with 0 +++

# nsenter --target $(pidof systemd-logind) --uts \
  strace -v -e uname ypdomainname
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="ember", release="5.4.70-1-lts",
       version="#1 SMP Wed, 07 Oct 2020 23:54:51 +0000", machine="x86_64",
       domainname="(none)"}) = 0
Local domain name not set
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

One workaround is to make sure your NIS services start before nss-user-lookup.target, as systemd-logind already declares ordering after this target – indicating that user lookup is available is precisely the purpose of this .target anyway:

```
# ypbind.service
[Unit]
Wants=nss-user-lookup.target
Before=nss-user-lookup.target
```

Another approach is to set the NIS domain name via `/etc/sysctl.d`, which is processed earlier than most services:

```
kernel.domainname = example.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. Together with the systemd documentation  for ProtectHostname it clarifies what is going on and why. In my answer to your comment I confirm that the problem does not occur when systemd-logind is started when NIS is active, Should I add a dependency in systemd-logind to wait for NIS before starting? The dependency is ypbind?

Comment: You helped me out again. Just like you did pointing out that systemd-logind must allow network traffic before NIS authentication is possible. I am upvoting this answer and marking it as the correct answer as it explains exactly what is causing the problem.